# How to connect tables together with multiple foreign and composite keys in Entity Framework 5.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 and I'm having trouble connecting two tables that each have a Composite Key. Each table also has a pair of foreign keys, one pair is a 1:1 relationship (tbd_AuditHistoryID AND taw_AuditHistoryID) and the other is 1:many (tbd_ParentAuditHistoryID and taw_ParentAuditHistoryID), that all reference the same field in a third table.

When running my code I get the following error: Unable to determine a composite foreign key ordering for foreign key on type t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister. When using the ForeignKey data annotation on composite foreign key properties ensure order is specified by using the Column data annotation or the fluent API.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("t_AuditHistory"), Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public System.Guid tbd_AuditHistoryID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Line_Number { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("t_AuditHistory"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public string tbd_ParentAuditHistoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual t_AuditHistory t_AuditHistory { get; set; }
}

public partial class t_TicketAsWorkedAuditRegister
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("t_AuditHistory"), Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public System.Guid taw_AuditHistoryID { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Line_Number { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("t_AuditHistory"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public string taw_ParentAuditHistoryID { get; set; }


    public virtual t_AuditHistory t_AuditHistory { get; set; }

}

public partial class t_AuditHistory
{

    public t_AuditHistory()
    {
        this.t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister = new HashSet<t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister>();
        this.t_TicketAsWorkedAuditRegister = new HashSet<t_TicketAsWorkedAuditRegister>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public System.Guid ah_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("t_AuditType")]
    public int ah_AuditTypeID { get; set; }   
    public string ah_AuditMessage { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("at_ID")]
    public virtual t_AuditType t_AuditType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<t_TicketAsWorkedAuditRegister>      
    t_TicketAsWorkedAuditRegister { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister>      
    t_TicketAsBillableAuditRegister { get; set; }
}
```

Any Help you could give would be greatly appreciated.